# A question on spaces with a point countable base?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Is there a normal Hausdorff space with a point countable base and a dense Lindelöf subspace which is not second countable?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this a normal Hausdorff space, or just a normal one? I don't know if that matters here; just want to be clear.

Comment: It is a normal Hausdorff space.

Comment: What do you know about similar questions?

Comment: @dfeuer: Let me think for a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following.

There exists a (regular) Lindelöf space $X$ with a point countable base which is not second countable (see [GMT, Ex. 9.4] or [Sak, Ex. 2.3]).  Let $P$ be a Bernstein set of the unit interval $I=[0,1]$. In other words, $P$
is an uncountable set which contains no uncountable closed set of $I$. Let $X$ be the space
obtained from $I$ by isolating the points of $P$. Obviously $X$ has a point-countable base. Note that every open set of $X$ containing $X\setminus P$ is co-countable, hence $X$ is Lindelöf.

Moreover, Eric K. van Douwen,  Franklin D. Tall and William A. R. Weiss in [DTW] under CH constructed a nonmetrizable  hereditarily  Lindelöf  space with  a  point-countable  base.

*References*

[DTW] Eric K. van Douwen,  Franklin D. Tall, William A. R. Weiss. *[Nonmetrizable  hereditarily Lindelöf spaces with point-countable  bases  from CH](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1977-064-01/S0002-9939-1977-0514998-1/S0002-9939-1977-0514998-1.pdf)*. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc., **64**:1 (May 1977), 139–145.

[GMT] G. Gruenhage, E. Michael, Y. Tanaka, Spaces determined by point-countable covers, Paciﬁc J. Math. **113** (1984), 303–332.

[Sak] Masami Sakai. *[Counterexamples on generalized metric spaces](http://www.jams.or.jp/scm/contents/e-2006-5/2006-49.pdf).* Scientiae Mathematicae Japonicae Online, **e-2006**, 539–542.